# Морфемный разбор слова «двести»

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Как разобрать слово *двести* по составу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом слове два корня: ***дв*** и ***ст***. И два окончания: ***е*** и ***и***.

Вот что пишет о подобных числительных Тихонов (см. его «Морфемно-орфографический словарь русского языка»):

> В сложных числительных *четыр-**е**-ст-**а**, четыр-**ем**-ст-**ам**,
>   четырь-**мя**-ст-**ами**, (о) четыр-**ех**-ст-**ах*** одно окончание
>   находится в конце слова, другое — внутри слова.